# How can I undo rm -rf $HOME/.rvm*

Tags: bash, vps, rvm

What does `rm -rf $HOME/.rvm*` mean?

I ran it on my VPS server in Ubuntu Terminal by accident and now I'm having all sorts of problems with my ruby application. How can I undo it? Or what do I need to do to get back to the way things were, before I did it?

Comment: See `man rm` for info on what it did. `*` is a wildcard that matches any character any number of times, so `.rvm*` means all files/folders whose name begins with `.rvm`. What you should do? Reinstall your Ruby application (or restore from a recent backup).

Comment: You deleted all the rvm configuration files/directory for the user you were logged in as.  Restore from backup, or re-install would be the common solutions.

Comment: @ernie -Not sure what you mean by 'restore from back up'? Could you tell me how to do that? I did get on to my VPS hosting company and they could restore it only to the 18th July, if that's what you mean. I did the mistake on the 17th - only realised the cause of it today, when I discovered the .bash_history file.

Comment: @Daniel Andersson - cheers, I'll look into that. When you say 'reinstall your ruby application', do you mean reinstall rvm?

Comment: @ChristopheHarris if you weren't keeping backups, then there won't be any.  Consider this a lesson learned.  You'll likely have to reinstall RVM, and then re-apply any custom settings/configurations you had.

Comment: Don't run commands that random people give you without understanding what they do first.

Answer (score 5):

Restore the deleted files from your fine backups that you should be keeping.

Comment: where would I find the 'fine back ups'? My hosting company said they keep records only as far as the previous week, which is too late for me.

Comment: Lessons are best learned the hard way. Firstly, don't run commands if you don't know what they do..seriously wtf? And second, have a backup strategy.

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to keep your application configuration in the project so assuming you have such files you should be able to rebuild environment from it:

1. install rvm again: `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`
2. load rvm into shell: `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm`
3. find the project directory, and cd to it: `cd ~/apps/my_app`
4. try to install and use ruby from the project: `rvm use --install --create .`
5. try to install gems from the project: `bundle install`

For the 4th step there should be most likely file called `.rvmrc` or `.ruby-version` but rvm can even try to detect ruby from `Gemfile`

For the 5th step most ruby applications use `Gemfile` to manage your gem dependencies.